# Ruby on Rails Each... do loop displays the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an app manage dentists and locations.  I just finished the location show page and added code to display a list of all the practitioners at that location.  However when I render the page, it is dumping the entire hash (locations.practitioner.each) above my formatted list.  How do I make the hash go away?

Here's my show.html.erb

```
    <p>
  <b>Location name:</b>
  <%= @location.location_name %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Location id:</b>
  <%= @location.id %>
</p>

<p><strong>Practitioners at this Location</strong></p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Production Goal</th>
    <th></th>

  </tr>

<%= @location.practitioner.each do |practitioner| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= practitioner.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= practitioner.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= practitioner.role %></td>
    <td><%= practitioner.production_goal %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_practitioner_path(practitioner) %></td>

  </tr> 
<% end %>
</table>
```

And here's how the page looks...

```
Location name: Waterview

Location id: 1

Practitioners at this Location

[#<Practitioner id: 1, first_name: "Dr. Robert", last_name: "Anjoux", role: "Dentist", production_goal: 10000, location_id: 1, created_at: "2013-03-26 17:34:38", updated_at: "2013-03-26 21:52:37">, 
#<Practitioner id: 3, first_name: "Smantha", last_name: "Hickleberry", role: "Hygenist", production_goal: 4800, location_id: 1, created_at: "2013-03-26 21:49:46", updated_at: "2013-03-26 21:49:46">, 
#<Practitioner id: 4, first_name: "Dr. Sandra", last_name: "Prenger", role: "Dentist", production_goal: 22000, location_id: 1, created_at: "2013-03-26 22:05:38", updated_at: "2013-03-26 22:05:38">]

**First Name    Last Name   Role    Production Goal**   
Dr. Robert  Anjoux          Dentist   10000                 Edit
Smantha     Hickleberry Hygenist   4800                 Edit
Dr. Sandra  Prenger         Dentist   22000                 Edit
```

What am I doing wrong?  I just what the tabular list...

Dennis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line is your problem. You are using the "=" sign which displays the output of the Ruby statement:

```
<%= @location.practitioner.each do |practitioner| %>
```

Change it to this:

```
<% @location.practitioner.each do |practitioner| %>
```

Comment: Rocking!  That did it just right.  All the tutorials said to use "<%=" so I dutifully did... to my own chagrin!  Thanks!!

Comment: can you point to the tutorials that said to use the version you did? :)

Comment: Yeah... More a id10t error than bad tutorial.  Just went back and checked and it was right on the .each do...  I just didn't pay attention and kept thinking that I needed to prefix all ruby commands with "<%=" which was the general instruction earlier in the tutorial.

Comment: Okay, cool :) Don't forget to upvote & accept sosborn's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Write it without the '=' symbol:

```
<% @location.practitioner.each do |practitioner| %>
```

Short explanation:

"ERB will evaluate this":

```
<%  %>
```

"ERB will evaluate and output this":

```
<%=  %>
```